# Ordenar elementos de Array

Tags: php, javascript, array, jsonobject, jsonarray

Como podría ordenar por "start_date" el siguiente array:

Nota: la data es una cadena tipo string (json), despues de convertirlo en Array, debo de ordenarlo por ese campo...

Puedo hacer con PHP o Javascript, como sea, pero lo importante es ordenarlo...

Muchas Gracias... les envio el Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Lunes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [start_date] => 09:30
                    [end_date] => 10:30
                    [text] => Texto de Ejemplo
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Lunes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [start_date] => 10:30
                    [end_date] => 11:30
                    [text] => Texto de Ejemplo
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Lunes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [start_date] => 08:30
                    [end_date] => 09:30
                    [text] => Texto de Ejemplo
                )
        )
)
```

Dichos datos los obtengo de la siguiente manera:

```
function test(){

    $data = '[{"Lunes":{"id":1,"start_date":"10:30","end_date":"11:30","text":"Texto de Ejemplo"}},{"Miércoles":{"id":2,"start_date":"08:30","end_date":"09:30","text":"Texto de Ejemplo"}},{"Lunes":{"id":3,"start_date":"09:30","end_date":"10:30","text":"Texto de Ejemplo"}}]';

    $json = json_decode(
        $data,
        JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
    );

    return $json;
}
```

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema. Podrias mirar tambien el [tour]?

Comment: Prueba con `usort()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar con `usort()`. puedes encontrar la documentacion de este [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php).

El uso de este en tu caso seria el siguiente:

```
<?php
    $datos = Array
    (
        Array(
                "Lunes" => Array
                    (
                        "id" => 1,
                        "start_date" => "09:30",
                        "end_date" => "10:30",
                        "text" => "Texto de Ejemplo"
                    )
            ),
        Array
            (
                "Lunes" => Array
                    (
                        "id" => 2,
                        "start_date" => "10:30",
                        "end_date" => "11:30",
                        "text" => "Texto de Ejemplo"
                    )
            ),
        Array
            (
                "Lunes" => Array
                    (
                        "id" => 3,
                        "start_date" => "08:30",
                        "end_date" => "09:30",
                        "text" => "Texto de Ejemplo"
                    )
            )
    );

    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a["Lunes"]["start_date"] == $b["Lunes"]["start_date"]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a["Lunes"]["start_date"] < $b["Lunes"]["start_date"]) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    echo "Datos sin ordenar:<br><br>";
    print_r($datos);
    echo "<br><br>Datos ordenados:<br><br>";
    usort($datos, "cmp");
    print_r($datos);

?>
```

Esto dara como resultado:

> Datos sin ordenar:
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [Lunes] => Array ( [id] => 1 [start_date] =>
>   09:30 [end_date] => 10:30 [text] => Texto de Ejemplo ) ) [1](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php) => Array
>   ( [Lunes] => Array ( [id] => 2 [start_date] => 10:30 [end_date] =>
>   11:30 [text] => Texto de Ejemplo ) ) [2] => Array ( [Lunes] => Array (
>   [id] => 3 [start_date] => 08:30 [end_date] => 09:30 [text] => Texto de
>   Ejemplo ) ) )
>
> Datos ordenados:
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [Lunes] => Array ( [id] => 3 [start_date] =>
>   08:30 [end_date] => 09:30 [text] => Texto de Ejemplo ) ) [1](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php) => Array
>   ( [Lunes] => Array ( [id] => 1 [start_date] => 09:30 [end_date] =>
>   10:30 [text] => Texto de Ejemplo ) ) [2] => Array ( [Lunes] => Array (
>   [id] => 2 [start_date] => 10:30 [end_date] => 11:30 [text] => Texto de
>   Ejemplo ) ) )

Comment: Gracias Samir, aunque en la Funcion cmp solo realiza la comparacion con "Lunes", pero olvide comentar que puede ser cualquier dia de la semana... ya con esto tengo la idea, añadire la funcionabilidad que funcione con cualquier dia de la semana.... ya os ire comentando.

Comment: vale si, se me paso por alto, pero la idea es esa

Answer (score 0):

Genial  @samir Todo Bien, al principio no me me funcionaba, pero no entendía porque en tu ejemplo si, al implementarlo, me di cuenta que tenia que usar un strtotime().

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a["Sabado"]["start_date"] == $b["Sabado"]["start_date"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return strtotime($a["Sabado"]["start_date"]) - strtotime($b["Sabado"]["start_date"]);
    //return ($a["Sabado"]["start_date"] < $b["Sabado"]["start_date"]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

El Dia de la semana, no pude colocarlo dinamicamente, lo que hice fue, una funcion para cada dia de la semana, no es muy elegante, pero si funcional.

De nuevo muchas gracias por la ayuda.